MS Excel Javascript add-in displays "loading" indefinitely
I have a JavaScript (Typescript) add-in for MS Excel that mostly works but display a 'loading...' message, along with a rotating icon indefinitely.
As a test, I created a brand new add-in using 'yo office' and accepting the choices for an MS Excel Typescript taskpane add-in.
Running this simple add-in also produces the same indefinite 'loading...' message.  This happens on 2 different systems, both Windows (one 11 the other 10; Excel version 2412).
Here are steps used:

follow the steps on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/develop-overview to create a new add-in using Yeoman.
yo office
Choose a project type: Office Add-in Task Pane project
Choose a script type: TypeScript
What do you want to name your add-in? SimpleTest
Which Office client application would you like to support? Excel
ran the add-in using npm run start
web pack ran and started Excel and I saw the Task Pane add-in as expected.
The 'Loading...' message appeared and never went away.

How do I get rid of the 'loading...' message?
